# Spring 4 TestNG +@Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, testng

Have a class in the package `com.conf`

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfTest {

    @Autowired
private Environment environment;

}
```

and unit test into `com.service`

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { WebConfTest.class })
public class DMSServiceImplTest {
    @Autowired
    WebConfTest webConfTest;

    @Test
    public void testConnect() throws Exception {

    }

}
```

test dependency :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

In the IDEA navigation between beans work. But `WebConfTest`== null if I run test.

What is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: put one more  `@service` annotation to `WebConfTest ` class. this might solve your problem

Comment: You try to autowire the config bean insde your test, not an actual bean available in the config

Answer (score 12):

`@RunWith` is for junit runner.

If you want to run tests with TestNG, you need to extends `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-support-classes-testng

Comment: Could you accept my response then and upvote it ? :)

Comment: Why do we need to extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests while running tests with testng.
IF I run without testng do I still need to exends the class.